# python - A better and shorter way to parse it?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, parsing

Is there a better way to structure the following three BLOCKS. My way seems to be very inneficient and it won't be easy to add more data extraction in the future. Perhaps using the re.compile sintaxis inside a tuple???

## BLOCK ONE

```
po_gen_execution    = re.compile(r'')
po_gen_start_date   = re.compile(r'')
po_gen_fileserver_host  = re.compile(r'')
po_gen_site         = re.compile(r'')
po_gen_grid_check   = re.compile(r'')
po_gen_params       = re.compile(r'')
po_nn_name      = re.compile(r'')
po_nn_launcher      = re.compile(r'')
po_nn_DbSourceMapping   = re.compile(r'')
po_nn_DbSource      = re.compile(r'')
po_ps_ps        = re.compile(r'')
po_ps_unit      = re.compile(r'')
po_ps_npid      = re.compile(r'')
po_ps_status        = re.compile(r'')
po_ps_start     = re.compile(r'')
po_ps_end       = re.compile(r'')
```

## END OF BLOCK ONE

```
def duration(ti, tf):
    ''' return time duration between tf and ti '''
    end = datetime.datetime.strptime(tf, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
    start = datetime.datetime.strptime(ti, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
    if start <= end: 
        return end - start
    else: 
        logging.info('Started before finish? check me!')
        return -1
# List of files to treat
gen_file_list = open(sys.argv[1])
G_dic = {}
for filename in gen_file_list.readlines():
    filename = filename.rstrip()
    G_dic[filename] = {}
    with open(filename) as f:
        G_dic[filename]['gen'] = G_dic[filename]['nn'] = G_dic[filename]['ss'] = {}
        filename = filename.rstrip()
        params = []
        for line in f:
```

## BLOCK TWO

```
LG_start_date   = po_gen_start_date.search(line)
LG_fileserver   = po_gen_fileserver_host.match(line)
LG_site         = po_gen_site.match(line)
LG_grid_check   = po_gen_grid_check.match(line)
LG_params       = po_gen_params.search(line)
LN_launcher     = po_nn_launcher.match(line)
LN_dbsm         = po_nn_DbSourceMapping.match(line)
LN_dbs          = po_nn_DbSource.match(line)
LP_unit         = po_ps_unit.match(line)
LP_pid          = po_ps_pid.match(line)
LP_status       = po_ps_status.match(line)
LP_end          = po_ps_end.match(line)
```

## END OF BLOCK TWO

## BLOCK THREE

```
if LG_params:
    params.append(LG_params.group(2).strip())
elif LG_start_date:
    LG_sd   = LG_start_date.group(1).strip()
    LG_st   = LG_start_date.group(2).strip()
elif LG_fileserver:  LG_fs   = LG_fileserver.group(1).strip()
elif LG_site:        LG_s    = LG_site.group(1).strip()
elif LG_grid_check:  LG_gc   = LG_grid_check.group(1).strip()
elif LN_launcher:    LN_l    = LN_launcher.group(1).strip()
elif LN_dbsm:        LN_d    = LN_dbsm.group(1).strip()
elif LN_dbs:         LN_db   = LN_dbs.group(1).strip()
elif LP_unit:        LP_u    = LP_unit.group(1).strip()
elif LP_npid:        LP_np   = LP_npid.group(1).strip()
elif LP_status:      LP_s    = LP_status.group(1).strip()
elif LP_end:
    LP_en   = LP_end.group(1).strip()
    LP_em   = LP_end.group(2).strip()
```

## END OF BLOCK THREE

```
start = LG_sd + " " + LG_st
end = LP_en + " " + LP_em

G_dic[filename]['gen'] = {
    'unit'      : LP_u,
    'fileserver'    : LG_fs,
    'site'      : LG_s,
    'exe params'    : params }
G_dic[filename]['nn'] = {
    'name'      : params[1],
    'launcher'      : LN_l }
G_dic[filename]['ps'] = {
    'name'      : params[0],
    'start'         : start,
    'end'       : end,
    'duration'      : str(duration(start, end)),
    'grid check'    : LG_gc,
    'pid'       : LP_np,
    'exit_code '    : LP_s }
```

Comment: What are you trying to parse?

Comment: I have to extract info from five kinds of text files... Two of those are logs, <timestamp - data> But the other three will be like the example, the info will normally appear once, and there is no timestamp

Comment: There are several python modules available for parsing. For example David Beazley's [ply](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/), or Paul McGuire's [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/).

I would suggest using one of those instead of writing your own.